# List of all users who can execute stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, permissions, stored-functions

I read several threads with similar question but none of them were providing full answer. I am searching for query which will show list of all users who can executed specific stored procedure. 
Result should show users regardless if they can execute stored procedure because of GRANT EXECUTE permission or because of his server role or because stored procedure can be executed by anyone.

Comment: Loop over all users, [impersonate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) each one and execute [`sys.fn_my_permissions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-my-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: The only exception from GSerg's suggestion is that you cannot execute as Windows groups. So if your users are all Windows users and not individual accounts this won't work

Comment: I have a mix of both SQL and Windows users/groups.

Comment: You don't need to impersonate a Windows group. You impersonate a Windows user, and your Windows group permissions will be taken into account.

Comment: @GSerg >>>You don't need to impersonate a Windows group. You impersonate a Windows user, and your Windows group permissions will be taken into account.<<<Imagine I have a server where ONLY WINDOWS GROUPS are mapped. So if you'll try to loop over users you'll always get the error that this kind of principal cannot be impersonated

Comment: @sepupic If that is so, then the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#_user) must be wrong, because it says that the Windows user must exist in the principals tables *unless* the impersonator is a member of sysadmin. I've done some testing being a member of sysadmin, and I can impersonate some users that are not explicitly added, but not some other users, and I'm not sure what's the difference between them.

Comment: @GSerg You misunderstood me. I did not say about sysadmin that can impersonate someone, I said that if all your users are presented as WINDOWS GROUPS, you cannot impersonate groups, and obviously every group can have many users but you cannot see them in any system table. I.e. if you have a user myDomain\myGroup, there are 100 members of that group, but you cannot execute the code "execute as user = 'myDomain\myGroup' even if you are sysadmin

Comment: @sepupic I didn't say you should. For that you would consult AD for the list of users.